# iOS AVFoundation Video overlay Video issues

Tags: ios, ios5, video, avfoundation, alpha

I having been crunching on the avfoundation framework for a few days now.  I am ale to successfully overlay and position CALayers and mash, export the final video with the exporter session.

I need to have a video with alpha transparency OVERLAY another video for the duration of the the video asset.  I cannot get this to work AT ALL.  Any help would rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial:  http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66

Looks like you need a bit of customization for your AVFoundation player, but it can be done.

Comment: Well, I stumbled upon that and I think it's good for playback, but I need to merge 2 tracks (top being transparent) and save out the new video asset... I have been googling this forays and just can't seem to find anything.  Action Movie Fx is doing it :) - so I am sure it can be done.

Comment: Let's chat. Try this room, it's open. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19284/ios-beginners

Comment: Hey Miles, sorry I missed this.  You up for arranging a chat tomorrow?  I would even be up for doing it through Google chat.  I'm stumped on this and there is not much out there to help :(

Comment: @ajs35 yep. Let's give it a shot. I'll keep that room open today in case you come by.

Comment: Well, it didn't work line by line, but shed light on a way to use AVAssets... I just need to read the whole article.  I would STILL like to figure out how to overlay a video with transparency, but that can hold for now.  Either - helped steer me in the right direction ;)

Comment: You cannot do it directly in iOS since h.264 does not support an alpha channel. But, there is a solution using a 3rd party library described in this linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812353/ios-overlaying-alpha-channel-video-on-another-video/21079559#21079559