# IOS I am trying to merge two videos ,one have alpha Channel，but it show blackbround

Tags: ios

I can not see the second video ,how to remove the background? ,the background is blackcolor,I try any ways ,but it is not work,I hope here can help .thank you

Comment: Where are you trying to merge your videos? Which program etc...?

Comment: I want to remove the frist video's background,like this http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVRender    AVRender Example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390447/avassettrack-with-alpha-channel  -----like this question