# How do I start with iPhone development for video

Tags: ios, iphone, video

So I started to realize that I need to learn something on iPhone video input and output to deal with OpenGL ES and the thing is that I don't know how to start with it. They say that it is good for a beginner to purchase a book about iPhone development and read it till you completely understand. However the thing I want to stay focused is about the video I/O of iPhone and I don't want to study other than that.

So is there any book or resource that explains video I/O quite well in Objective-C? If not, it's okay to recommend some books written in Swift.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079559/763355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/
and Tutorial
http://www.appcoda.com/video-recording-playback-ios-programming/
and Advance video project example link 
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Thanks for the answer